# Background Thread to upload data to Firebase

Tags: swift, multithreading, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, grand-central-dispatch

Where would I run a background thread in my app in order to upload data to my Firestore DB.

The app will either be in the background or terminated, I will still need to upload the info to the server even if the user has closed the app

This code seems to execute the Thread, But where should it be placed? Can i put it in my applicationDidEnterBackground or applicationWillTerminate?

```
DispatchQueue.background(background: {
    let checkPointWorker = CheckPointWorker()
        checkPointWorker.writeCheckPointsToFirestore()
}, completion:{
    // Background job finished
})
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use case that requires writing to the database even when the user has terminated the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can put your code inside `applicationDidEnterBackground` /  `applicationWillTerminate` but there is no guarantee that it'll successfully be uploaded to firebase as the time the app is being a live after it's sent to background or inside willTerminate depends entirely on the pressure of currently opened apps at that time , and honesty the app will be closed by IOS if it does an extensive task while it's not in foreground

You can go with background fetch

https://medium.com/@vialyx/ios-dev-course-background-modes-fetch-70c18f9f58d5

and use it for an upload instead of a download , but it's better to make that upload when the app is opened again